# switching the google sign in button android

Tags: android, button, google-signin, google-plus-signin

I am pretty new with android and I want to switch the google sign in button image with my own designed one, how can I do it?

Here is my current google button(In which I want to switch the image but cant..)

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
    android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:src="@drawable/login"
    android:layout_gravity="center |bottom"/>
```

Comment: You can define your own button and set it's id to "sign_in_button" (or any id name you want) and set an onClickListener to the button and call the signin method inside it.

Comment: Note that Google has [specific brand guidelines](https://developers.google.com/identity/branding-guidelines) how logos must be used for actions like the login. It may not be allowed to use a custom graphic, or use it in the wrong way.

Answer (score 3):

try it

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnLoginGoogle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/google_icon"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_google_btn"/>
```

onClick

```
case R.id.btnLoginGoogle:
    loginWithGoogle();
    break;

public void loginWithGoogle(){
     try {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_GET_TOKEN);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```